# how to get the user attribute from aws cognito in c#

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am using AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient SDK.
I am trying to get a custom attribute for user in cognito. from c# front end i am passing username , password and email id. is there any function  to retrieve the  user atribute from cognito ?

Comment: Have you succeed login and getting the token (access, I'd, & refresh) ?

Answer (score 1):

After Cognito successfully authenticates a user in your pool, you will receive several JWTs - an access token, an ID token, and a refresh token. These tokens can be accessed in the authentication result object that is returned by the SDK (`InitiateAuthResponse`).

You can verify and decode the ID token to unpack the claims about the user's identity. This will also include any custom attributes you have defined on your User Pool. For .NET you can use `JwtSecurityTokenHandler` to decode the JWT (`Sytem.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` namespace). After decoding the token, access the `Claims` property to get the user information. Custom attributes are prefixed with `custom:`, while Cognito attributes (such as username) are prefixed with `cognito:`.

Here's an AWS doc on how to decode the token: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-verifying-a-jwt.html

Here's an example on how to use `JwtSecurityTokenHandler`: https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/manually-validating-rs256-jwt-dotnet/

You can also use the Access Token to use the SDK to lookup a user directly, and the response from the AWS SDK will include the user attributes. Here's the doc on that: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_GetUser.html

Answer (score 1):

Try `Amazon.CognitoIdentityProvider.AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient.GetUserAsync()`, it will return all standard and custom attributes. Please note that the method will only return the attributes for which a value is set.